# Class nesting and access modifiers

Tags: c#, class, nested

I have following piece of code:

```
class A
{
    public C GetC()
    {
        return new C();
    }
}

class B
{
    //has access to A but can not create C. Must ask A to create C.
    private void method()
    {
        A a = new A();
        C c = a.GetC();//Ok!
        C c2 = new C();//Not allowed.
    }
}

class C
{

}
```

What access modifiers should be used on C so it is ONLY accessible through A? (only class A knows how to properly initialize class C)
Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe make class C a nested class of A with a private constructor.

Comment: I've tried that and it won't work as C constructor is private.

Comment: Are A, B and C in the same assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make A a nested class in C it should work.

```
public class B
{
    //has access to A but can not create C. Must ask A to create C.
    private void method()
    {
        var a = new C.A();
        var c = a.GetC();//Ok!
        var c2 = new C();//Not allowed.
    }
}

public class C
{
    private C()
    {
    }

    public class A
    {
        public C GetC()
        {
            return new C();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit A from C, and make Constructor of C protected
**EDIT** -- "as protected member cannot be accessed via qualifier ", error is coming, as a work around, static member is introduced which will return the instance. This protected member is accessible from derived.

```
class A : C
{
    private C GetC()
    {
        C c = C.GetC();
        return c;
    }
}

class C
{
    protected C()
    {
    }
    protected static C GetC()
    {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot access protected member 'TestNamespace.C.C()' via a qualifier of type 'TestNamespace.C'; the qualifier must be of type 'TestNamespace.A' (or derived from it)

Answer (score 0):

Proposed method Inherit A from C, and make Constructor of C protected code doesn't work because in it are some errors. Adjusted this method code  is below:

```
class B
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        C c = a.GetC();
        C c2 = C(); //Non-invocable member 'C' cannot be used like a method
    }
}
class A : C
{
    public new C GetC()
    {
        C c = C.GetC();
        return c;
    }
}

class C
{
    protected C()
    {
    }
    protected static C GetC()
    {
        return new C();
    }
}
```